# JavaScript arguments being cached unintentionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my php file, I'm calling this jQuery plugin with

```
<script>$.notifications('resources/notifications.inc.php');</script>
```

I previously had the php file at:

```
resources/dashboard.notifications.php
```

and later moved it to what I have now, which is:

```
resources/notifications.inc.php
```

The issue I'm having is it's like *caching* the arguments and still showing the old notifications php file for the requestUrl. I've cleared my cookies and everything. What should I do? I have no idea where the old value is being stored.

Here's the plugin I'm calling.

```
$.extend({
    notifications: function() {
        Notifications.requestUrl = arguments[0];
        console.log(Notifications.requestUrl + " and " + arguments[0]);
        Notifications.interval = arguments[1] || 15000;

    }
});
```

Finally the output I'm getting in the console. (The unexpected token in JSON is coming from the non-existent php file that it's trying to request)
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To16k.png)

Comment: In which browser are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: check your codebase, I think you are calling `$.notifications` somewhere in your code with old file. because its logging two times, use developer tool bar have a break point and see that call stack .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it **was** in fact being called a second time, in another file *dashboard.js*